# Constrained read-only field in a DB (especially with PostgreSQL and Django ORM)

Tags: database, django-models, constraints, relational-database

I am building a relational DB structure, where one of the table (e.g. **events** table) represent time ranges with a start date.

This table have the following fields that can be modified:

- **event.start_date**: DateTime
- **event.duration**: TimeDelta

The **end_date** can be compute doing:

```
end_date = event.start_date + event.duration
```

I have code that retrieve elements from this table, and that make heavy use of the **end_date** property.

Is there a way to store it somewhere in the table, so that it is read_only, and that if **event.start_date** or **event.duration** is modified, then it is updated.

> The idea is to have a consistent  and not redundant DB, but a fast
>   access to 'resultant' values (such as **end_date**).

The icing of the cake being having also a **event.end_date** field and:

- if the **event.duration** is updated, then **event.end_date** is updated.
- if **event.end_date** is updated, then **event.duration** is updated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to myself:

It seems that [PostgreSQL trigger procedures](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) (DB-engine level) or [Django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/signals/) (application level) do the job.